# C# implement interface on "where TEntity : class"

Tags: c#, generics, interface, generic-constraints

I'm relatively new to **.NET** and I've stumbled on this particular issue: while following a tutorial on repository pattern, the definition of the class goes like this:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class { ...
```

That being said, this class is supposed to implement an interface. Since I already used the `:` operator, how do I do that?

I tried going `public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository where TEntity : class {` and also `public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class : IGenericRepository {` but it doesnt work

Comment: do you mean the generic parameter should implement an interface or the type itself ?

Comment: @Selman22 I assumed the latter ("this class is supposed to implement an interface"), but it's not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since I already used the : operator, how do I do that?

`:` isn't an operator - you're just using it in the generic type constraint. You can still specify an interface to implement.

This should be fine:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository where TEntity : class
```

Or if `IGenericRepository` is a generic interface, you might want:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
```

Comment: Accepted this answer because the interface is also a generic and it was also confusing how to declare: `... : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where...`

Answer (score 0):

Use a comma to add multiple generic constraints:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IGenericRepository {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd say
`public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : BaseClass1, IInterface1, IInterface2, ... where TEntity : class { ...`

The `:` you used refers to the generic type parameter needing to be a `class` (rather than a `struct`), so you can add an additional "`:`".

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : **IGenericRepository**<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

or

In my case all classes are inheriting from IdentityBaseClass thus my signature looks like:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IdentityBase
```

Having said that what it mean is my classes, whoever  wants to use GenericRepository, must inherit from IdentityBase class.

My IdentityBase class has got two properties.

```
 public class IdentityBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets ID.
        /// </summary>
        [NonNegative]
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the unique identifier of a row; this is to do with replication in SQL.
        /// </summary>

        public Guid UniqueIdentifier
       { 
            get;
            set;
        }
```